aggrid use column filters as search in treedata
I want to use filters in my columns in a grid with 2 levels of treedata.  If the filter is for a column in the child level, then i would like the following to happen -

Any child cell that meets the filter background color changes.
Any siblings are  not filtered.
Any parents that do not have children that meet the filtered are no longer in the grid.

I am using Javascript.  Any advice on how to accomplish this?  I have included a picture based on another grid control I have been using.  I would like to switch to aggrid.
In the picture below you can see I have searched on 2 columns in the child rows.  They are highlighted with the parent.  All sibling rows are in the grid.  I had to hand code the search.  Is this possible to do with the filters in aggrid.  thanks.

